# sed replacing special string quota

Tags: sed

sed is still giving me headaches, so a little help is extremely appreciated.

In a file I have a string like:

```
SOME_TEXT="variables"
```

What I want to accomplish is to add a piece of text (variable) to either the end or the begging of the string for that text.

I tried to use variations of:

```
sed -i '/^SOME_TEXT="/ s/$/ SOME_TEXT="new text'/' filename
```

but that is failing, so clearly the quota for the string I want to add to is messing up the syntax.

---

LE:
A variation further is that I have a variable that I want to use as the replace in that syntax, so I have this:

```
sed -i "s/^SOME_TEXT="/SOME_TEXT=" $variable/" file
```

This actually produces this output, as it picks up incorrectly the opening/closing quotas:

```
SOME_TEXT = text_variable" initial text continuation
```

So how can I properly close the trailing quota so that I can use the variable  after it?

Comment: you need to use double quotes to have the variable expanded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used

```
sed  's/^SOME_TEXT="/SOME_TEXT="new text/' filename
```

and it showed:

```
SOME_TEXT="new textvariables"
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks Martin, that did the trick as it it. I've edited my post as I want to use a variable as the replacement text, and since I must use double-quotas, those are messing up between the sed syntax and the fact that my text has one in it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the `'"'` characters with a `'\'` so that they don't terminate your regex string.

```
sed -i "s/^TEXT=\"/TEXT=\" $variable/"
```